# Error upon collecting after join in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Spark 1.4.1. I have a couple of DataFrames that I want to join on a userid field. It seems that the join works, because I can see the schema and print out a count of how many rows there will be (216 in this case):

```
usersearch_jnd = rr.join(uu, rr.searcher_id == uu.userid, 'inner')
print(usersearch_jnd)
print(usersearch_jnd.count())
usersearch_jnd.printSchema()

DataFrame[min_age: int, max_age: int, inter_in: int, zoom: int, searcher_ethnicity: array<bigint>, searcher_id: int, searcher_sex: int, offset: int, searchee_id: int, searchee_loc: struct<latitude:double,longitude:double>, userid: int, search_users_interested_in: int, search_level: int, search_max_age: int, search_min_age: int, search_ethnicity_multi: string, search_looking_for_sex: int, interested_in: int, search_distance: float, ethnicity: int]
216
root
 |-- min_age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- max_age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- inter_in: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- zoom: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- searcher_ethnicity: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- searcher_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- searcher_sex: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- searchee_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- searchee_loc: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- userid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- search_users_interested_in: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- search_level: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- search_max_age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- search_min_age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- search_ethnicity_multi: string (nullable = true)
 |-- search_looking_for_sex: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- interested_in: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- search_distance: float (nullable = true)
 |-- ethnicity: integer (nullable = true)
```

However, when I do something as simple as collect() or head(), I run into errors:

```
usersearch_jnd.collect()
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-191-86046817e0ea> in <module>()
----> 1 usersearch_jnd.collect()

/Users/evanzamir/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in collect(self)
    279         """
    280         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 281             port = self._sc._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jdf.javaToPython().rdd())
    282         rs = list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    283         cls = _create_cls(self.schema)

/Users/evanzamir/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/Users/evanzamir/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 307.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 307.0 (TID 2628, localhost): scala.MatchError: (VALUE_STRING,IntegerType) (of class scala.Tuple2)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JacksonParser$.convertObject(JacksonParser.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:193)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedIterator$$anon$3.writeNext(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.spillToPartitionFiles(ExternalSorter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Any ideas what I can check?

Comment: Try dropping None values

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Thank you!!! I dropped a column that seemed to have all None values. Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: The issue is not with None values, you are trying to convert a String value into a Integer, but not in a correct way. Type conversion a bit tricky sometimes between RDDs and Dataframes. Can you add the `explain` method output of the `usersearch_jnd` ? Can you also perform a count on `rr` ?